# Return NULL JavaScript

Tags: c#

I don't understand why I am getting alert "Empty" when I type some numbers or leave a empty? Can you help me?

My Code:

```
    </script> 

               <script type="text/javascript">
                   function tell() {
                       var v = true;
                       if (document.getElementsByName("TextBox33").length == 0)
                       alert("Empty");
                           v = false;

                       return v;
                   }
</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" OnClientClick="javaScript: return tell();"

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox33" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("imei") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

I am adding more html:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="286px" OnItemInserting="DetailsView1_ItemInserting" OnDataBound="DetailsView1_DataBound" OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted">

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IMEI" SortExpression="imei">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("imei") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox33" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" CssClass="TextBox33" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("imei") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("imei") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: GetElementsByName returns a collection. It's empty not the TextBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling getElementsByName which returns al array of DOM elements. You're then taking the length of that, which will always be more than 0 because the element exists.

Try adding a `[0]` after the getElementsByName call, and then change `.text` to `.value`.

Also so you're aware, you need to put the `alert` and `v = false` inside brackets. You can only skip brackets if you're executing one statement.

Here's the revised code:

```
if (document.getElementById("TextBox33").value.length == 0){
    alert("Oh no I'm empty!");
    v = false;
}
```

Update: I also just noticed that you didn't actually give the textbox a name of TextBox33, you gave it an ID. I've updated the code.

Comment: Sure, I added it to the answer.

Comment: I have got error:

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Comment: My bad, I'm typing on a phone. I had ID in all caps, it's Id. Try now.

Comment: Yes, Luke, I have tried with ID, but the problem is same and I don't know why...
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Yes.
document.getElementById("TextBox33").value.length == 0

Comment: Yes, I have checked but I don't understand my error of Unable to get property 'value'

Comment: I would view the source of your page and make sure the input has an id set. Can you post the input element's actual HTML source?

Comment: I have added to my question more html elements.

Comment: Oh I meant the raw HTML, the stuff that asp is generating for you. I'm not familiar with asp so I'm not sure if it is doing something weird that's causing an issue.

Comment: I have found, I have changed ClientIDMode to Static of DetailsView1.